# Possible duplicate comment not showing anymore?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, comments, vote-to-close

Link: [In R, sorting character vectors: how to specify sorting orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18989960/in-r-sorting-character-vectors-how-to-specify-sorting-orders)

Just voted to close it, but the usual "possible duplicate" comment didn't show. Why?

Snapshot:

[image]

Comment: There seems to be something that makes it not generate the comment if the proposed dup question has already been mentioned in comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The comment is only added if the question hasn't already been mentioned in a comment on the post.  We don't think there's a reason to notify the user a second time essentially.